# jQuery UI datepicker setDate and moment.js

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, momentjs, jquery-ui-datepicker

jQueryUI datepicker doesn't seem to play nicely with moment.js

I need my datepicker to preset to last 90 days, so `FromDate` should be 90 days ago and `ToDate`  is today.

```
$('#FromDate').datepicker({
    format: 'dd-M-yyyy',
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoclose: true,
    orientation: 'auto bottom'
});

$('#ToDate').datepicker({
    format: 'dd-M-yyyy',
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoclose: true,
    orientation: 'auto bottom'
});

var todate = new moment();
var fromdate = new moment().subtract(90, "days");
$("#FromDate").datepicker("setDate", fromdate);
$("#ToDate").datepicker("setDate", todate);
```

This throws an error

> ```
> JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'getTime'
> ```

Is there something I am missing? It looks like a formatting issue?

Comment: You can set the default date in DatePicker as `"-90d"`. Not sure where `getTime` is comming into play as I do not even see a reference to that method in your script.

Answer (score 3):

From jQuery UI [`setDate`](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate) doc:

> Sets the date for the datepicker. The new date may be a `Date` object or a string in the current [date format](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) (e.g., `"01/26/2009"`), a number of days from today (e.g., `+7`) or a string of values and periods (`"y"` for years, `"m"` for months, `"w"` for weeks, `"d"` for days, e.g., `"+1m +7d"`), or `null` to clear the selected date.

In your code, you are passing a moment object as argument of [`setDate`](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate) so the jQuery datepicker is not able to manage it. You can convert your moment objects to native JavaScript dat using [`toDate()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) method.

Here a live sample:

```js
$('#FromDate').datepicker({
  format: 'dd-M-yyyy',
  todayHighlight: true,
  autoclose: true,
  orientation: 'auto bottom'
});

$('#ToDate').datepicker({
  format: 'dd-M-yyyy',
  todayHighlight: true,
  autoclose: true,
  orientation: 'auto bottom'
});

var todate = moment();
var fromdate = moment().subtract(90, "days");
$("#FromDate").datepicker("setDate", fromdate.toDate());
$("#ToDate").datepicker("setDate", todate.toDate());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="FromDate">
<input type="text" id="ToDate">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a different DatePicker as `format`, `todayHighlight`, `autoclose`, and `orientation` are not options for jQuery UI DatePicker.

Here is a pure jQuery UI example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#FromDate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy'
  });

  $('#ToDate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy'
  });

  $('#FromDate').datepicker("setDate", "-90d");
  $('#ToDate').datepicker("setDate", "0");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>From
    <input type="text" id="FromDate" />
  </p>
  <p>To <input type="text" id="ToDate" /></p>
</div>
```

See More: [jQuery UI API | DatePicker | setDate](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate)